# Jasmine Tests Fail when Boot.js Included

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have bunch of tests which I was running through Visual Studio but now I am trying to implement the tests such that I can run them through the command line using **Karma**.  After trying to use Karma my tests started to fail so I assumed that this was Karma's fault but now I think it might be linked to **Jasmine**.

I think it is linked to Jasmine because I started only including files I really needed into my **karma.config.js** file.  I removed **jasmine/boot.js** and my tests stopped failing.

Let's say I have a test in this format...(as an *example*)

```
describe("", () => {
    console.log("describe1");
    beforeEach(() => {
        console.log("beforeEach");
    });

    describe("", () => {
        console.log("describe2");
        it("", () => {
            console.log("it1");
        })

        it("", () => {
            console.log("it2");
        })
    });
});
```

What would happen is my first **describe** would run, then the second **describe** and then the **beforeEach** and then the first **it** and so on.  The problem was that after my test successfully ran it would run the **it**s again without running the **beforeEach** and thus the tests would fail.

**Example Output of Above Code**

```
describe1
describe2(note that the "it"s are not executed)
beforeEach
it1
beforeEach
it2(so far so good but now...)
it1(notice how before each didn't run but the "it"s were reran here and below)
it2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had an older version of Jasmine and jasmine/boot.js only needs to be included after Jasmine 2.0